# How do I match an Id in one collection to a nested list of Ids in other collection

Tags: arrays, mongodb, list, elixir, aggregation

I have two collection systems and multi controller systems, multi controller systems has list of Ids:

```
"systemIDs" : [
    NumberInt(1000), 
    NumberInt(1001), 
    NumberInt(1002), 
    NumberInt(1003)
],
```

And systems document has a field of systemID: `"systemID" : NumberInt(1526312340)`,

Multi Controller system also has a multiControllerID.

What I am trying to achieve is find if any of systemIDs in multicontroller system matches the systemID in systems and set the multiControllerID field in systems equal to the multiControllerID in MultiControllerSystems collection.

so if systemIDs includes systemID set mcsID (in systems collection) equal to mcsID(from multi controller system collection)

Comment: Welcome shubham arya! Please provide few sample documents from both collections and the expected output for them.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.